# Report Builder Positioning Controls at Runtime

Tags: delphi, report, reportbuilder

I'm using Delphi 2010 with ReportBuilder 10.04 and have a very basic report with 1 detail band containing 2 TppDBText components (one with bold text and the other non-bold). Both are printing on the report at their specified positions defined at design time, as expected. What I need to be able to do is reposition the control to the right as close as possible to the end of the text of the other control (which contains varying text lengths). Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting up the `AfterPrint` event of the component on the left? Maybe its width will be set accordingly to the text it got, an then you can properly position the component on the right.

Comment: Yes I've tried that but this didn't work. All the Widths were set to the same for the first control.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I tried this a few times but never got it right. For vertical positioning there's `ShiftRelativeTo`, but nothing similar to horizontal positioning. Maybe use a Rich Text control and format it after setting the text?

Answer (score 0):

First, for this example to work, set the TppReport's 'Units' property to 'utScreenUnits'.

I will use City and State fields as an example here, and my dataset is called 'tblCustomers'.

In the DetailBand's BeforePrint property add the following code:

```
// ppCity is a tppDBText report control
// ppState is a tppDBText report control

ppCity.Width := length(tblCustomersCity.asstring) * 10; //adjust 10 based on font size
ppState.left := ppCity.Left + ppCity.Width + 10; // adjust 10 based on font size
```

You could also do this with calculated fields, but since your first control is bold and your second control is not bold, the above should suffice.

To use a calculated field, simply combine City and State into one calculated field called 'CityState', and in the OnCalcs of the dataset do the following:

```
tblCustomerCityState.asstring := tblCustomersCity.asstring +' '+tblCustomersState.asstring;
```

Comment: Just note that this is an approximation, so use a big enough multiplier (*in this example it's 10*). This is best combined with monospaced fonts.